# как записать в json файл несколько значений с Python кода

Tags: python, json, bs4, lxml

**Задача записать в json файл 4 значения которые были спарсины**

```
for items in items:
    name = items.find('div', class_="iva-item-titleStep-2bjuh").find('span', class_="title-root-395AQ iva-item-title-1Rmmj title-list-1IIB_ title-root_maxHeight-3obWc text-text-1PdBw text-size-s-1PUdo text-bold-3R9dt").text
    price = items.find('div', class_="iva-item-content-m2FiN").find('div',class_="iva-item-body-NPl6W").find('span', class_="price-root-1n2wM price-list-14p4v").find('meta').next.get('content')
    currency = items.find('div', class_="iva-item-content-m2FiN").find('div',class_="iva-item-body-NPl6W").find('span', class_="price-root-1n2wM price-list-14p4v").find('meta').get('content')
    links = items.find('div', class_="iva-item-content-m2FiN").find('div', class_="iva-item-titleStep-2bjuh").find('a').get('href')
    print(f'{name} | {price}{currency} | {links}')
```

**Должно быть вот так**

> Джойстик PS4 (геймпад). Цвет: тёмно-синий | 1290RUB |
> /chelyabinsk/igry_pristavki_i_programmy/dzhoystik_ps4_geympad._tsvet_temno-siniy_2002116207

Comment: А почему только 4? У вас там список товаров, почему не список сохранить? Или под 4-мя не имеется ввиду name, price, currency, links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас там список товаров, поэтому предлагаю сохранить в [json](/questions/tagged/json) список из словарей.

Пример:

```
import json

json_data = []
for items in items:
    ...
    print(f'{name} | {price}{currency} | {links}')
    json_data.append({
        "name": name,
        "price": price,
        "currency": currency,
        "links": links,
    })

with open("products.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```